# CSS Анимация прокрутка текста по кругу

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть массив, состоящий из 20 слов. Нужно сделать прокрутку текста по кругу 1 раз в секунду, чтобы каждое следующее слово заменяло предыдущее. Я вижу примерно так:

[image: примерно так]

Не могу придумать, как реализовать такую логику отображения. Если заменять слова просто js кодом, то как к этому прикрутить css-анимацию?
Я вижу так, чтобы прописать:

```
<style>
        .scrolls .inactive{
            display: none;
        }
        .scrolls .postactive{
             /*animation code*/
        }
        .scrolls .preactive{
            /*animation code*/
        }
        .scrolls .active{
            /*style code*/
        }
</style>
<ui class="scrolls">
        <li class="active">World 1</li>
        <li class="postactive">World 2</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 3</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 4</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 5</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 6</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 7</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 8</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 9</li>
        <li class="inactive">World 10</li>
        <li class="preactive">World 11</li>
    </ui>
```

Но как тогда изменять классы?

Comment: Допустимо ли использование jQuery в проекте?

Comment: @Romanzhivo Ну в целом да, но лучше было б без него так как я в этом проекте использую AngularJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант, но с `Jquery` (в принципе можно и под нативный переделать):
*P.S. смотреть в Chrome*

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".active").prev().removeClass('active stap2 ').addClass('active2');
  $(".active").prev().removeClass('stap1');
  $(".active").prev().addClass('stap2');
  $(".active").addClass('stap1');
  $(".active").next().addClass('active');
  clearInterval();
}, 2000);
```

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    left: 50px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes example2 {
  0% {
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    left: -50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes out {
  0% {
    left: 50px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100px;
    top: 100px;
  }
}
.scrolls {
  list-style: none;
}
.start {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name: enter;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.active2 {
  display: block;
  animation-name: out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.stap1 {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.stap2 {
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ui class="scrolls">
  <li class="start active ">World 1</li>
  <li class="start ">World 2</li>
  <li class="start">World 3</li>
  <li class="start">World 4</li>
  <li class="start">World 5</li>
  <li class="start">World 6</li>
  <li class="start">World 7</li>
  <li class="start">World 8</li>
  <li class="start">World 9</li>
  <li class="start">World 10</li>
  <li class="start">World 11</li>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: rot 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

span {
  padding-left: 3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes rot {
  from { transform: rotate(0) }
  to { transform: rotate(1turn) }
}
```

```html
<div><span>Слово 1</span>
  <div><span>Слово 2</span>
    <div><span>Слово 3</span>
      <div><span>Слово 4</span>
        <div><span>Слово 5</span>
          <div><span>Слово 6</span>
            <div><span>Слово 7</span>
              <div><span>Слово 8</span>
                <div><span>Слово 9</span>
                  <div><span>Слово 10</span>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то нужен примерно такой вариант с "очередью":

**Скрипт, стили, разметка:**

```js
var array = [
  'Слово 1',
  'Слово 2',
  'Слово 3',
  'Слово 4',
  'Слово 5',
  'Слово 6',
  'Слово 7',
  'Слово 8',
  'Слово 9',
  'Слово 10'
];
var count = 0;
var word = document.querySelectorAll('.one-word')[0];
console.log(word)
word.innerHTML = array[count];
setInterval(function() {
 if(count != array.length - 1) {
  count++
  } else {
   count = 0;
  }
  word.innerHTML = array[count];
},1000);

setInterval(function() {
 if(word.className == 'one-word') {
   word.className = 'one-word hide'
  } else if(word.className == 'one-word hide') {
   word.className = 'one-word hide-2'
  } else if(word.className == 'one-word hide-2') {
   word.className = 'one-word show'
  } else if(word.className == 'one-word show') {
   word.className = 'one-word show-2'
  } else if(word.className == 'one-word show-2') {
   word.className = 'one-word'
  }
},200);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.words {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #868686;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.one-word {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.one-word.hide {
  left: -100%;
}
.one-word.hide-2 {
  left: auto;
  right: -100%;
  display: none;
}
.one-word.show {
  left: auto;
  right: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.one-word.show-2 {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="words">
    <div class="one-word"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/cgx4ja8d/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @Romanzhivo    Спасибо за ваш отзыв, он мне очень помог.